# Numba: can't locate cuda libraries

Tags: anaconda, numba

I'm trying to take advantage of cuda with my gtx 1080 on windows, I installed cuda toolkit 10 from nvidia website and set up the environment variables using this tutorial on medium: [tutorial](https://medium.com/@minhplayer95/how-to-install-tensorflow-with-gpu-support-on-windows-10-with-anaconda-4e80a8beaaf0)
However' when I ran `numba -s` command on anaconda prompt I got the following message:

```
Finding cublas
    ERROR: can't locate lib
Finding cusparse
    ERROR: can't locate lib
Finding cufft
    ERROR: can't locate lib
Finding curand
    ERROR: can't locate lib
Finding nvvm
    located at C:\Users\Nimrod Naim\Anaconda3\DLLs\nvvm64_32_0.dll
    finding libdevice for compute_20... ERROR: can't open libdevice for compute_20
    finding libdevice for compute_30... ERROR: can't open libdevice for compute_30
    finding libdevice for compute_35... ERROR: can't open libdevice for compute_35
    finding libdevice for compute_50... ERROR: can't open libdevice for compute_50
Found 1 CUDA devices
id 0     b'GeForce GTX 1080'                              [SUPPORTED]
                      compute capability: 6.1
                           pci device id: 0
                              pci bus id: 7
Summary:
    1/1 devices are supported
```

thus cuda won't be enabled using numba.

Can you please help me solve that problem?

Thanks!

Comment: you need to install cuda from inside Anaconda

Comment: I installed cuda with anaconda after I installed cuda toolkit using Nvidia and it still didn't work, should I remove the other version?

Comment: Do you have a 64 bit Anaconda installation?

Comment: Yes I can ensure that my anaconda is 64bit

Comment: Do you tried setting variables http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/installing.html#installing-using-pip-on-x86-x86-64-platforms

Answer (score 0):

for cublas : `sudo apt-get install cuda-cublas-[version]`

`nvidia-smi` give the cuda version.

Other libs were installed by default (cuda 10-2 for me). Otherwise, packages are named like `cuda-cusparse-`[use completion to see available version, take the good one : ex: `sudo apt-get install cuda-cusparse-10-2`]

Same problem now, solution:
put those lines in ~/.profil :

```
export NUMBAPRO_CUDALIB=/usr/local/cuda/lib64
export NUMBAPRO_LIBDEVICE=/usr/local/cuda/nvvm/libdevice
export NUMBAPRO_NVVM=/usr/local/cuda/nvvm/lib64/libnvvm.so
```

(note that cuda here has the path /usr/local/cuda/, correct if needed)